# Accesing external ip port with traefik router

Tags: docker, traefik

---

### Unable to routing external ip/port

I'm following this [guide](https://github.com/techno-tim/techno-tim.github.io/tree/master/reference_files/traefik-portainer-ssl/traefik) and unable to route the external IP into the subdomain, resulting to nothing while internal port (installed portainer in docker) seems working. Exposing to the public is my next plan. Following is my yml config

```
docker-compose.yml
```

Exposed 80 and 443 port from the router, DNS name server also pointed on my digitalocean then pointed into my traefik-dashboard.local.example.com -> public-IP by using A-record

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
      - DO_AUTH_TOKEN=TOKEN
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /root/container/traefik/data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - /root/container/traefik/data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - /root/container/traefik/data/acme.json:/acme.json
      - /root/container/traefik/data/config.yml:/config.yml:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik-dashboard.local.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=admin:password"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.sslheader.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik-dashboard.local.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=digitalocean"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=local.example.com"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.local.example.com"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"
    expose:
      - 80
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

```
data/traefik.yml
```

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  debug: true
  insecure: true
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"
serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    filename: /config.yml
accessLog: {}
log:
  level: debug
certificatesResolvers:
  digitalocean:
    acme:
      email: email@example.com
      storage: acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: digitalocean
        delayBeforeCheck: 0
        #resolvers:
        # - "1.1.1.1:53"
        # - "1.0.0.1:53"

pilot:
  dashboard: false

metrics:
  prometheus:
    entryPoint: traefik

accessLog:
  filePath: "/var/log/traefik/access.log"
  filters:
    statusCodes:
      - "400-600"
`      ``api:
  dashboard: true
  debug: true
  insecure: true
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"
serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    filename: /config.yml
accessLog: {}
log:
  level: debug
certificatesResolvers:
  digitalocean:
    acme:
      email: email@example.com
      storage: acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: digitalocean
        delayBeforeCheck: 0
        #resolvers:
        # - "1.1.1.1:53"
        # - "1.0.0.1:53"

pilot:
  dashboard: false

metrics:
  prometheus:
    entryPoint: traefik

accessLog:
  filePath: "/var/log/traefik/access.log"
  filters:
    statusCodes:
      - "400-600"
```

The dashboard appeared with healthy server,
[image: traefik-dashboard]

```
data/config.yml
```

I'm toggling this config on/off and the problem still persists.

```
http:
  routers:
    pihole:
      entryPoints:
        - "https"
      rule: "Host(`pihole.local.example.com`)"
      middlewares:
        - default-headers
        - addprefix-pihole
      tls: {}
      service: pihole
  services:
    pihole:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://192.168.0.20:80"
        passHostHeader: true
  middlewares:
    addprefix-pihole:
      addPrefix:
        prefix: "/admin"

    https-redirect:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https

    default-headers:
      headers:
        frameDeny: true
        sslRedirect: true
        browserXssFilter: true
        contentTypeNosniff: true
        forceSTSHeader: true
        stsIncludeSubdomains: true
        stsPreload: true
        stsSeconds: 15552000
        customFrameOptionsValue: SAMEORIGIN
        customRequestHeaders:
          X-Forwarded-Proto: https
```

Already assigned A record in pi-hole, dns, seems doesn't do anything magic, the pihole.local.example.com still appeared blank.

Let me know if there's anything wrong with my config.

Attached below is my log
https://pastebin.com/raw/R1w9jR7U